# using if statement within for loop

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
for (int i=0; i<=83; i++)
    {
        GameObject btns = Instantiate (buttoneg.gameObject) as GameObject;      
        btns.gameObject.GetComponent<LevelButton> ().levelNo = i + 1;
        if(btns.gameObject.GetComponent<LevelButton>().levelNo<maxlvlreached)
        {
        btns.gameObject.GetComponent<LevelButton>().button.image.color=Color.green;
        }
 }
```

Here is my code, what i want to do is keep checking if statement throughout the loop,but for some reason it doesn't ,help will be appreciated.
Thank You !

Comment: What kind of error you get? Isnt `maxlvlreached` type bool?

Comment: have you checked the value of `maxlvlreached`?

Comment: no, maxlvlreached is integer,i am fetching it from playerpref,i don't get any error ,it just does not work

Comment: as AntiHeadshot stated, `Debug.Log` values, like `Debug.Log((i + 1) + " | " + maxlvlreached)`. Also try to store the component as GetComponent method is quite expensive.

Comment: you are just using `i+1` so why don't you change your loop to `for (int i=1; i<=84; i++)`, and you should think about using a parameter to store the `83` or in this case `84`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was ,i was calling the for loop first and then setting maxlevelreached in start method,sorry noob programmer here.